# Questions about Adobe Director 12's creation of apps for Apple's iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, adobe-director

Does Director 12 have to be on an Apple computer to create iOS apps?

Does the creation of iOS apps still work today (and can an app be published on the Apple App Store) if I use an older Apple computer?

Adobe's fine print says that Adobe gets a cut of each iOS app sale; is this still true?

Comment: Since director 12 support ended in 2017 it is highly unlikely that you can still use it to create and publish iOS apps. Apple requires that apps submitted today use the iOS 16 SDK, which would not be part of a program from 2017

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, that's why I was wondering whether there was anyone familiar with the process.  Perhaps Director outputs a generic blob that then gets compiled by a modern iOS SDK/Xcode?  Sadly, but understandably, I see there is little traffic on this forum.